1064 when try to mysqldump
There is a problem, when I try to create a dump file inside my C# project, it just give 1064 error no matter how do my code looks like...

    public class MySQLBackup
    {
        private string connectionString;
        private string backupPath;

        public MySQLBackup(string connectionString, string backupPath)
        {
            this.connectionString = connectionString;
            this.backupPath = backupPath;
        }

        public void Backup_OnClick()
        {
            try
            {
                using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    string dbName = connection.Database;
                    string backupFile = Path.Combine(backupPath, $"{dbName}_{Convert.ToString("Backup")}.sql");
                    string query = $"mysqldump -v -h localhost -u root -p qwerty123ZZZ {dbName} > {backupFile};";
                    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection))
                    {
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        Console.WriteLine("Success");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }

    private void BackupMethod(object? sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string connectionString = "server=localhost;user=root;password=qwerty123ZZZ;port=3306;database=rsodatabase;";
        string backupPath = @"C:\Backup";
        MySQLBackup backup = new MySQLBackup(connectionString, backupPath);
        backup.Backup_OnClick();
    }

I was waiting for this code to be able to create a dump file of my database, but unfortunately it only gives errors over and over again..

mysqldump -v -h localhost -... isn't a SQL query. It's the command line used to execute the mysqldump application with specific arguments from a terminal. If you want to execute an external application use the Process class. The MySQL exception thrown by MySqlCommand is probably telling you there's a syntax error.

@PanagiotisKanavos can you show me what it would look like with an example?

The Process class docs show how to call any application and pass arguments to it. mysqldump.exe is a program just like chrome.exe or ping.exe. If the program's location is in the path, you could use Process.Start("mysqldump",$"-v -h localhost -u root -p qwerty123ZZZ {dbName} --result-file={backupFile}";. Notice that --result-file is used instead of redirection. A dump isn't really a backup, it's a script of the entire database. MySQL has no BACKUP command.
